# repeat a matching value in another column by factored group

Tags: r, string, date

I have a dataframe `examp` that has a column `A` with strings that are dates or words. They are either in the excel format beginning with `4` or in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Using my factored `id` column I'd like to create a new column called `Date` that looks at column `A` and converts only the strings that are dates in that column to an actual date. The `Date` column should repeat the matched date value for every `id` factor level.

This is an example of my data:

```
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), A = c("2015-04-30", NA, 
NA, NA, "43220", NA, NA, NA, "2014-04-30", NA, NA, NA, "2008-05-30", 
NA, NA, NA, "2012-03-31", NA, NA, NA), val1 = c(12.5846281409471, 
10.4624600058284, 11.4755754286143, 14.701688181697, 13.8405475026281, 
13.004572814877, 7.72203471371193, 13.7606513736878, 12.4136524221556, 
10.6791971268818, 12.3554296419778, 11.2009080049977, 13.1858720282748, 
12.4583870312518, 14.1838110701387, 12.5430358199843, 12.2190413098143, 
14.096471309436, 12.360573242374, 12.6067718045824), val2 = c(34.8949657555743, 
31.1540833974875, 31.0088433621199, 43.0588053956557, 33.1324369995825, 
37.4651979318779, 39.7380042954774, 43.6837424041797, 39.2399727601316, 
30.1360902228072, 30.2985229201897, 32.9737294189259, 29.6223913098321, 
38.9078239846969, 45.7976491432947, 28.6114892141713, 25.862618117394, 
35.9858613120554, 34.8668513118929, 43.6680483315073)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

These are all the values in column A:

```
c(NA, "42674", "42766", "43131", "43404", "43039", "42704", "43434", 
"43069", "42735", "43100", "42794", "43159", "43190", "42825", 
"43220", "42855", "43251", "42886", "43281", "42916", "43312", 
"42947", "43343", "42978", "43373", "43008", "43585", "43951", 
"43708", "43465", "43830", "43524", "43890", "43496", "43861", 
"43677", "43646", "43555", "43921", "43616", "43982", "43799", 
"43769", "43738", "42643", "2011-07-31", "2012-02-29", "2008-04-30", 
"2012-04-30", "2013-04-30", "2015-04-30", "42490", "2009-04-30", 
"2010-04-30", "2011-04-30", "2014-04-30", "2012-08-31", "2013-08-31", 
"2015-08-31", "42613", "2008-08-31", "2009-08-31", "2010-08-31", 
"2011-08-31", "2014-08-31", "2008-12-31", "2012-12-31", "2013-12-31", 
"2015-12-31", "2009-12-31", "2010-12-31", "2011-12-31", "2014-12-31", 
"2013-02-28", "2015-02-28", "2010-02-28", "2011-02-28", "2014-02-28", 
"2016-02-29", "2013-01-31", "2014-01-31", "2016-01-31", "2009-01-31", 
"2010-01-31", "2011-01-31", "2015-01-31", "2012-01-31", "2012-07-31", 
"2013-09-30", "2015-07-31", "42582", "2008-07-31", "2009-07-31", 
"2010-07-31", "2014-07-31", "2012-06-30", "2013-06-30", "2015-06-30", 
"42551", "2008-06-30", "2009-06-30", "2010-06-30", "2011-06-30", 
"2014-06-30", "2012-03-31", "2013-03-31", "2015-03-31", "42460", 
"2009-03-31", "2010-03-31", "2011-03-31", "2012-05-31", "2013-05-31", 
"2015-05-31", "42521", "2010-05-31", "2011-05-31", "2014-05-31", 
"2008-11-30", "2012-11-30", "2013-11-30", "2015-11-30", "2009-11-30", 
"2010-11-30", "2011-11-30", "2014-11-30", "2008-10-31", "2012-10-31", 
"2013-10-31", "2015-10-31", "2009-10-31", "2010-10-31", "2014-10-31", 
"2012-09-30", "2015-09-30", "2008-09-30", "2010-09-30", "2011-09-30", 
"2014-09-30", "2009-02-28", "2008-05-30")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the pattern in the data we can change the dates and use `tidyr::fill` to fill the `NA` values based on `id`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = if_else(grepl('^\\d+$', A), 
                as.Date(as.numeric(A), origin = "1899-12-30"), as.Date(A))) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  tidyr::fill(date)

#    id    A           val1  val2 date      
#   <fct> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
# 1 1     2015-04-30 12.6   34.9 2015-04-30
# 2 1     NA         10.5   31.2 2015-04-30
# 3 1     NA         11.5   31.0 2015-04-30
# 4 1     NA         14.7   43.1 2015-04-30
# 5 2     43220      13.8   33.1 2018-04-30
# 6 2     NA         13.0   37.5 2018-04-30
# 7 2     NA          7.72  39.7 2018-04-30
# 8 2     NA         13.8   43.7 2018-04-30
# 9 3     2014-04-30 12.4   39.2 2014-04-30
#10 3     NA         10.7   30.1 2014-04-30
#11 3     NA         12.4   30.3 2014-04-30
#12 3     NA         11.2   33.0 2014-04-30
#13 4     2008-05-30 13.2   29.6 2008-05-30
#14 4     NA         12.5   38.9 2008-05-30
#15 4     NA         14.2   45.8 2008-05-30
#16 4     NA         12.5   28.6 2008-05-30
#17 5     2012-03-31 12.2   25.9 2012-03-31
#18 5     NA         14.1   36.0 2012-03-31
#19 5     NA         12.4   34.9 2012-03-31
#20 5     NA         12.6   43.7 2012-03-31
```

Note that this will generate a warning since we are using `as.numeric` on string like `2015-04-30` but it is safe to ignore. We can also use `suppressWarnings()` to suppress them.

---

We can also break this down in steps to avoid warning and error :

```
df$date <- as.Date(NA)
x1 <- grepl('^\\d+$', df$A)
x2 <- grepl('\\d+-\\d+-\\d+', df$A)
df$date[x1] <- as.Date(as.numeric(df$A[x1]), origin = "1899-12-30")
df$date[x2] <- as.Date(df$A[x2])
df %>% group_by(id) %>% fill(date, .direction = 'updown')
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: 'Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
In addition: Warning message:
In as.Date(as.numeric(C), origin = "1899-12-30") :
  NAs introduced by coercion'

Comment: Are you using on the data that you have shared? It works fine for me as shown for that data (I do get the warning).

Comment: Let me edit the question and provide the unique dates from the column. I can't share the entire dataframe.

Comment: Will it matter if the date string in column A isn't the first entry for every new id?

Comment: @gm007 No it will not matter but if that is the case you need to add `fill(date, .direction = 'updown')` to fill `NA`s at the top as well as bottom . can you try the updated answer?

Comment: I still get this error: Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: okay there was a typo in my answer. Can you check now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223386/discussion-between-gm007-and-ronak-shah).